# Looking for an example of an $A$-algebra $B$ that is a free $A$-module of rank $1$, and the ring map $A\to B$ is not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Looking for an example of an $A$-algebra $B$ that is a free $A$-module of rank $1$, and the ring map $A\to B$ is not surjective

It seems harder than I thought....Any simple example? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Rings are assumed to be commutative and with $1$.)

It cannot happen. In fact, such $A\to B$ must be an isomorpshim.

*Proof.* Let $\varphi\colon A\to B$ be the ring map.
Since $B$ is free of rank $1$, choose an isomorphism $f\colon A\xrightarrow{\sim}B$ of $A$-modules.
Let $b=f(1)$.
Let $a\in A$ be the element such that $f(a)=1$ in $B$.
Then it follows that
\begin{equation}
1=f(a)=\varphi(a)f(1)=\varphi(a)b,
\end{equation}
hence $b$ is a unit in $B$.
Consider the composite
\begin{equation}
g\colon A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{b^{-1}}B,
\end{equation}
which is an isomorphism of $A$-modules, where $B\xrightarrow{b^{-1}}B$ is defined by multiplication by $b^{-1}$.
Then $g$ is an $A$-homomorphism which maps $1$ to $1$, hence is equal to $\varphi$.
This shows that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.